How to constrain motion tracking to 3D gemetry?
I previously did motion tracking on a handful of frames and got an acceptable solution.
When I added markers to additional frames and asked Blender to compute a solution, the camera locations for the previous frames changed dramatically.
I have some geometry that matches the reference images. How do I tell Blender that certain markers should map to fixed 3D locations? (Is there some other way to prevent Blender from completely wrecking whatever clip-to-scene alignment I've already done?)

I don't think this is possible, at least not without Python. One reason being, a camera tracking can't know about the absolute distance between trackers, only the relative positions.
